# Tricky RegExp question? How would I do this?

Tags: javascript, regex, frontend, regexp-replace

I want a simple validation `<word must be Locate with length 6,SPACE,1 length integer,COMMA, 1 length integer,COMMA, 1 word must be either UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT>` and case of words don't matter.  How would I do this?  Preferably I'd like to do this using RegExp and I'll have an array of strings.
i.e.) `LOCaTe 9,0,uP`

I have a simple array ["Locate", "9", "," ,"4", "up"] .  This array will work.  If I have an array like ["Locate"," asdf", "9", "," ,"4", "up"] that array wont work.  It has to be a string then number then comma then number then string.

Comment: Did you forget your code? We have no idea what you're trying to do!

Comment: Can you give us more examples?

Comment: Relax I updated it please help.

Answer (score 2):

I guess regex might not be necessary here, and you can likely script that with some methods similar to:

```js
function check(arr = arr) {
 if (arr.length !== 5) {
  return false;
 }

 if (arr[0].toLowerCase() !== 'locate') {
  return false;
 }


 if (parseInt(arr[1]) === NaN || parseInt(arr[3]) === NaN) {
  return false;
 }

 if (arr[2] !== ',') {
  return false;
 }

 if (arr[4].toLowerCase() === 'up' || arr[4].toLowerCase() === 'left' || arr[4].toLowerCase() === 'right' || arr[4].toLowerCase() === 'down') {
  return true;
 } else {
  return false;
 }

 return true;
}

arr = ["Locate", "9", ",", "4", "UP"]
console.log(check(arr))
```

---

If you had to write an expression, then maybe an expression similar to:

```
^\[\s*"locate"\s*,\s*"\d"\s*,\s*"\s*,"\s*,\s*"\d"\s*,\s*"(?:up|down|right|left)"\s*\]$
```

might be OK to look into.

```js
const regex = /^\[\s*"locate"\s*,\s*"\d"\s*,\s*"\s*,"\s*,\s*"\d"\s*,\s*"(?:up|down|right|left)"\s*\]$/gmi;
const str = `["Locate", "9", "," ,"4", "up"]
["LOCATE" , "8" , "," , "4", "down"]
["LoCATE" , "3" , "," , "0", "right"]
["LoCate" , "2" , "," , "5", "left"]
["LoCate" , "21" , "," , "5", "left"]`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/PKt4uN/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/PKt4uN/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert the array into string (using [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)), and then check the string with regExp.

```js
function isValidArray(arr) {
  let str = arr.join(';');
  return (new RegExp(/(locate);\d;,;\d+;((up)|(down)|(left)|(right))/gi)).test(str)
}

const arr1 = ["Locate", "9", "," ,"4", "up"];
const arr2 = ["Locate"," asdf", "9", "," ,"4", "up"] ;

console.log(isValidArray(arr1)); // return true
console.log(isValidArray(arr2)); // return false
```